# How to load mp3 files from RAW Folder instead of SDCARD

Tags: java, android, arraylist, mp3, media-player

Hello I was looking at this tutorial [on the web](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) :   But it has some bugs and dont seen to be working right.

I just wanted to find out, how to load my MP3 files locally from the RAW Folder insted of the SDCARD as in the code below. thanks

```
public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you Are Asking for

**> How to load my MP3 files locally from the RAW Folder insted of the SDCARD**

Ans is:

```
MediaPlayer mplayer;    
mplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundfile);// it is the file that you save in ur raw folder 
mplayer.start();
```

**If you Want complete example**

You Can Try This code:

```
package com.hrupin.mp3player;

import com.hrupin.mp3player.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class Mp3player extends Activity {

    private Button buttonPlayStop;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SeekBar seekBar;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    // Here i override onCreate method.
    //
    // setContentView() method set the layout that you will see then
    // the application will starts
    //
    // initViews() method i create to init views components.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            initViews();  

    }

    // This method set the setOnClickListener and method for it (buttonClick())
    private void initViews() {
        buttonPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
        buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override public void onClick(View v) {buttonClick();}});

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testsong_20_sec); 

        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            seekChange(v);
            return false; }
        });

    }

    public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }else{
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    } 

    // This is event handler thumb moving event
    private void seekChange(View v){
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
        }
    }

    // This is event handler for buttonClick event
    private void buttonClick(){
        if (buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {
            buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));
            try{
                mediaPlayer.start();
                startPlayProgressUpdater(); 
            }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        }else {
            buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw` resource IDs with your media playback class, like `MediaPlayer`. So, for example, if you have `res/raw/resources_are_not_files.mp3`, you would use `R.raw.resources_are_not_files` to reference that MP3 for methods like [`create()` on `MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29).

Comment: One doubt.. if we load .mp3 file in raw folder that will reflect in .apk size.?

Comment: @S3a2r0a8v9a6n9a: Yes, MP3 files packaged in your APK will increase the size of the APK. Since an MP3 is already a compressed format, the APK size will increase by approximately the size of the MP3 file itself. Hence, this technique is mostly good for short sound effects and the like, not hours of music.

Answer (score 0):

Place the mp3 files in **raw** folder and use this way

```
MediaPlayer mplayer;
mplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yoursound);// create & refer the id
mplayer.start();//will play the file
```

For more detail check this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm